# Javascript add new line to table and replace IDs

Tags: javascript

I'm a hobby coder and struggle with following issue:
I got a table element with a few rows, each row 3 cells. Via a button at the bottom I would like to add rows. The table looks like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr id="line[0]"><td id="cellA[0]"</td><td id="cellB[0]"</td><td id="cellC[0]"</td></tr>
  <tr id="line[1]"><td id="cellA[1]"</td><td id="cellB[1]"</td><td id="cellC[1]"</td></tr>
  <tr id="line[2]"><td id="cellA[2]"</td><td id="cellB[2]"</td><td id="cellC[2]"</td></tr>
</table>
```

I loop through with elementbyID "line" to find that the last line is [2]. And then add a new line like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
var row = table.insertRow(oldID + 1);
row.setAttribute("id","line["+ oldID + 1 + "]");
```

This works great.

Next I get the content of the last line via var lastLine = document.getElementById(oldID).innerHTML. Now since the td IDs are cellA[2], cellB[2] and cellC[2]. I would like to replace those with [3].

I tried following:

```
var oldVar = "[" + oldID + "]";
var newVar = "[" + oldID + 1 + "]";
var regex = new RegExp(oldVar, "g");
var neueLine = lastLine.replace(regex, newVar);
```

but this results in ids like this "cellA[3][3]", "cellB[3][3]" and "cellC[3][3]".

I feel like my limited knowledge is missing out on the supposed way to do this.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use replaceAll

```
lastLine = lastLine.replaceAll("[" + oldID + "]","[" + (oldID+1) + "]")
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly. 

I knew I was missing something really simple. 

Thanks a lot for the fast answer.

Comment: @Matthias Sweet!

Comment: This will use regexp on HTML, not necessarily just the ID

Answer (score 1):

This will work - it can possibly be coded in less instructions but is very readable. Also I fixed the invalid HTML

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const table = document.querySelector("#mytable tbody");
  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    const lastRow = table.querySelector("tr:last-child")
    let id = +lastRow.id.replace(/\D+/g, ""); // grab and convert to number
    let newId = id+1;
    const newLine = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
    newLine.id = newLine.id.replace(id,newId);
    newLine.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(cell => cell.id = cell.id.replace(id,newId))
    table.appendChild(newLine)
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="line[0]">
      <td id="cellA[0]">A</td>
      <td id="cellB[0]">B </td>
      <td id="cellC[0]">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="line[1]">
      <td id="cellA[1]">A </td>
      <td id="cellB[1]">B</td>
      <td id="cellC[1]">C </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="line[2]">
      <td id="cellA[2]">A</td>
      <td id="cellB[2]">B</td>
      <td id="cellC[2]">C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```